# How to correctly receive data using ZeroMQ?

Tags: zeromq

I have two machines in the same network :

1. The first machine binds to a socket on its own IP address (`120.0.0.1`) and receives any data coming to the socket `.bind()`-ed on port `5555`:

   ```
   zmq::context_t context{1};   
   zmq::socket_t socket{context, ZMQ_SUB};
   socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE,  "lidar");

   socket.bind("tcp://120.0.0.1:5555");

   while(true)
   {
      zmq::message_t message;
      auto recv = socket.recv(message);
      ROS_INFO("Value: %d", recv.value());
   }
   ```
2. The second machine, having an IP address `120.0.0.248`, connects to the first machine and sends the messages to it:

   ```
   sock.connect("tcp://120.0.0.1:5555");
   while (1) {
     double nodes[8192];
     sock.send(zmq::buffer("lidar") , zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
     sock.send(zmq::buffer(nodes, (((int)(count)) * 8)));
   }
   ```

But for some reason, I cannot receive any messages on the first machine and it gets stuck on `auto recv = socket.recv(message);`.

What is a correct way for such communication?

Comment: Would you mind to show the complete code? This is by far not an MCVE code, is it?

Comment: Is your sender a PUB socket? I would normally bind the PUB socket ("the server") and connect the SUB sockets ("the clients").